# Oracle Merge delete clause where data in target but NOT in source

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Trying to delete records from a Target table that are NOT in the source table.

***Object Type***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type dbo.P_REC AS OBJECT
(
    ATTR1    VARCHAR2(64 BYTE),
    ATTR2    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
    ATTR3    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
    ATTR4    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
);
```

***Collection Type***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type dbo.P_REC_LIST is table of P_REC;
```

***Stored Procedure***

```
PROCEDURE testProc(tmpPList IN P_REC_LIST, resultCursor out sys_refcursor)

IF tmpPList.count > 0 THEN
MERGE INTO [targetTable] TT
        USING (SELECT abc.Attr1 abc.Attr2 FROM TABLE(tmpPList) abc) TMP
        ON (TT.Attr1 = TMP.Attr1)
      WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET TT.Attr2 = TMP.Attr2 
        DELETE WHERE TT.Attr1 NOT IN (SELECT Attr1 FROM TABLE(tmpPList))
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (Attr1)
        VALUES (TMP.Attr1);
END IF;
```

Currently, I can start from a truncated table and the insert portion works. When run again the update portion works.
But when a record is removed from tmpPList, IE, no longer in the source data the record remains in the target table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a [MERGE delete](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g#delete_clause) *Only those rows in the destination table that match both the ON clause and the DELETE WHERE are deleted.*

You may `FULL JOIN` the table with your `TMP` in the `USING` query and make use of a flag to delete the unmatched rows.

```
create or replace  PROCEDURE testProc(tmpPList IN P_REC_LIST)
AS
BEGIN
 IF tmpPList.count > 0 THEN
MERGE INTO targetTable tt
        USING ( with abc as
                 (
                  select * from TABLE(tmpPList)
                  )
                  select COALESCE(abc.attr1,t.attr1) as attr1,
                                     abc.attr2,CASE WHEN abc.attr1 IS NULL
                                           THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END 
                                          match_flag FROM abc
                          FULL JOIN targetTable t ON t.attr1 = abc.attr1
               ) tmp
        ON (tt.Attr1 = tmp.attr1)
      WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET tt.Attr2 = tmp.Attr2 
        DELETE WHERE match_flag = 'Y' --This flag to identify the unmatched row
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (Attr1)
        VALUES (tmp.Attr1);
  END IF;
END testProc;
/
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ab308e6fd3f3f88c98c336c8d1a2444)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: When I add the addition of a LEFT JOIN on a materialized view in the USING clause and try to check multiple column values in the UPDATE WHERE clause the DELETE clause seems to fail and does not remove a record. Are you able to provide additional help?

Comment: @XmlevolentX : This answers your original question. If you have further questions, you should consider asking a new one with latest details rather than unaccepting an accepted answer.

Comment: Noted.
Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Im trying to replicate this solution on my example but I dont understand where the 'match_flag' is coming from?
I am getting the following error in SQL: 
'match_flag
Error report -
Unknown Command'

Comment: @KaushikNayak The match flag is identifying the rows that need to be deleted from the target table.

Comment: i think there is an easier way : left join the target table then NVL2(t.attr1, 'Y','N')