# select from a oracle table which is not created,and no type created in databse

Tags: sql, oracle, function

like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type P_REC AS OBJECT
(
    ATTR1    VARCHAR2(64 BYTE),
    ATTR2    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
    ATTR3    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
    ATTR4    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
);
CREATE OR REPLACE type P_REC_LIST is table of P_REC;


DECLARE
tmpPList P_REC_LIST := P_REC_LIST(P_REC('A1','A2','A3','A4'),
                                  P_REC('B1','B2','B3','B4'),
                                  P_REC('C1','C2','C3','C4') 
                                  );
BEGIN
   testProc(tmpPList);
END;
```

then I can write:

```
 select * from TABLE(tmpPList)
```

but the problem is I do not want create any type in database,because the database is forbidden to change schema.

I want write like so:

```
select * from ( ( ('att1','att2','att3','att4'),('att1a','att2a','att3a','att4a') ) ) t
```

but it is not allowed in syntax.

### Is there any way to select a table on the fly?

**the final goal is the same as this post:[merge and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657309/oracle-merge-delete-clause-where-data-in-target-but-not-in-source)
but the point is I can not create a type in oracle**

Comment: Huh?  How do you expect to select from a table that does  not exist?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I can write all the records in sql to compose a table, like an in-memory table.

Comment: please update the  question with what you are trying to achieve? so that  people can understand  what you are thinking

Comment: [Oracle table functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm#CHDCIEJG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard SQL you would use the `VALUES` row constructor.

```
select * from (values ('att1'), ('att2'), ('att3'), ('att4')) t(attr)
```

but Oracle still doesn't support it.

You can select the single values (for which in Oracle you must select from `DUAL`) and then use `UNION ALL` to get the whole data set:

```
select 'att1' as attr from dual
union all
select 'att2' as attr from dual
union all
select 'att3' as attr from dual
union all
select 'att4' as attr from dual;
```

For more columns, select more columns :-)

```
select 'att11' as attr1, 'att12' as attr2, 'att13' as attr3 from dual
union all
select 'att21' as attr1, 'att22' as attr2, 'att23' as attr3 from dual
```

Comment: Oracle hides feature requests in a discussion board which is hard to search and known to few. If you register, you can upvote feature requests (called database ideas there). Here is the link to the request for the `VALUES` clause: https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4391390/add-support-for-the-values-constructor. It got added in 2016 and only got 42 upvotes so far, because there are just so very few people knowing this forum and using it.

Answer (score 0):

Although Oracle does not support yet the `VALUES` row constructor of the standard sql, you can use the internal `odcivarchar2list` for that purpose.

```
SQL> select * from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('value1','value2','value3')) ;

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
value1
value2
value3
```

If your values are numbers, then you can use `odcinumberlist`

```
SQL> select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5,6)) ;

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           1
           2
           3
           4
           5
           6

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: how can I get a two or more columns table?

Comment: odcinumberlist and odcivarchar2list are not designed for that. they convert a list of values into a list of rows.  But you can combine them in very different ways. Although your case matches what table functions are intended for